# Python: unexpected end of pattern

Tags: python

This regex is used for removing all php comments. Could you please check the regex?

```
content = ""
    with open(file_path, 'r') as content_file:
        content = content_file.read()

re.sub(r"""(?|(?:#|//)([^\r\n]*)|/\*([\s\S]*?)\*/)""", "", content)
```

What's wrong with my regex? Thanks.

Comment: What's your input, and what output are you expecting?

Comment: What do you want it to do ? Help us help you by providing the text you are trying to match. And get rid or the triple quotes `r"(?|(?:#|//)([^\r\n]*)|/\*([\s\S]*?)\*/)"`. Try this [interactive online python regex debugger](http://www.pythonregex.com/).

Comment: @JonClements, this regex is used for removing all php comments. I got unexpected end of pattern error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's certainly something wrong in the part  `(?|(?:#|//)`
The question marks acts as a quantifier for the first paren `(`
Then your regex pattern is equivalent to

```
('(?'
 '|'
 '(?:#|//)([^\r\n]*)'
 '|'
 '/\*([\s\S]*?)\*/)'
 )
```

And if you test `re.compile('(?|a')` , you'll obtain the same error as the one you relates : `unexpected end of pattern`

By the way, `[\s\S]` represents any character, `\n` comprised; you can replace this with a dot `.` accompnied with the flag `re.DOTALL`

Comment: '(?|' I just removed this part and it worked. Thank you for your guide.